# What could cause nichrome wire to overheat and melt?

Tags: heat-transfer

Yesterday

I wasn't careful enough with my popcorn maker and I managed to break it. The kernels probably restricted the air flow and something blew up. It stopped working and about 2 seconds after that a cloud of grey fog came out.

I disassembled it (I have okayish understanding of electrical components) and right away noticed that the coil was burned (melted) and broke in half. I reconnected the broken ends to see if it will work again, and to my surprise it did, but for only 2 seconds. Coil got glowing red and once again broke.
I disassembled an old blowdryer and reused the nichrome coil that it had to replace the wire. And yet again, it got glowing hot in about 2 seconds and the wire melted.

I really don't know much about this and I don't want to experiment too much so I would rather ask here for opinion. Could this be a problem with thermal fuse? or something else is wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how did you reconect the heating element?

Comment: I attached the coil on the holes that held the last coil in place. I don't know the exact name of it but it's basically a hole with a metal cap.

Comment: there is nothing wrong ... it is behaving as it should ... you cannot shorten the heating element ... the shorter section will have lower resistance than a full length element ... as a result, it will draw more current, get hotter, and melt

Comment: **brake** *verb*
e.g. make a moving vehicle slow down or stop by using a brake. **break** *transitive verb*
e.g. to separate into parts with suddenness or violence.

Answer (score 1):

The heater element in an electrical appliance like this requires air to be blown over it so it will not get too hot. So for the case where the appliance fan is not running, or the air flow through the fan is obstructed for some reason, the wire will indeed overheat and melt.

Comment: Yeah, that does make a lot of sense. I had to desolder the fan because it was impossible to test it with the vibrations. Thank you, I will put the new coil in and reassemble it back.

Answer (score 0):

Overheat causes failure. It may overheat because of too much current flow, or restricted (cooling) air flow, or because it has been shortened ( Shorter reduces resistance and permits more current flow at the same voltage), or higher resistance  caused by a poor connection may cause local overheating.  Another possibility for some consumer products is that they are not Nichrome but Kanthal, low cost iron alloy which becomes very brittle after use and is unrepairable. No solder can possibly work on a Nichrome heating element.